# retrieving all the x[i]-th elements of RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
entries = sc.textFile(...).map(lambda line: line.split("\t")).map(lambda row:(int(row[0]),row[1]))
some_set = set()
for entry in entries.collect():
    some_set.add(entry[1])
```

Is there a better way to do the above. I just want to get the i-th element of each entry.

Comment: Why you want to avoid collect, when you are collecting values? Run `entires.map(x => x[0]).collect()`

Comment: you are right. I framed the question incorrectly. Wanted to know if all x[i] could be stored into an set/list without loading entire RDD into the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically what you describe is:

```
set(entries.keys().distinct().collect())
```

or generalized

```
set(entries.map(operator.itemgetter(i)).distinct().collect())
```

Comment: it doesn't have to be the 1st element

Comment: so is the 2nd solution better than entries.collect() ? Is this because it collects only the x[i]-th element instead of the entire RDD ?

Comment: It is better because it `collects` only `distinct` elements. It you want local `set` you won't do better. If you want just unique stop at `distinct`.